# webview.goBack() throws error: UIManager.dispatchViewManagerCommand got 2 arguments, expected 3 - React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-webview

I'm trying to make custom navigation controls for the react-native-webview.
The app throws this error (in andorid & ios): 
[image: error]

This is my first app in React Native, but I'm experienced with React for web development. I really don't know how to debug this error. I'm not sure if this error is because a bug react-native-webview or a bug in my own code.

**The code**

```
export default class BrowserScreen extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { canGoBack: false };
}

backHandler = () => {
  if(this.webview){
    this.webview.goBack(); //this throws and error
  }
}

forwardHandler = () => {
  this.webview.goForward();
}

_refWebView = (webview) => {
  if (!webview) {
    return;
  }
  this.webview = webview;
}

render() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container} >
      <View style={styles.controls}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={this.backHandler}
        >
          <Text style={styles.icon}>⬅️</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    <WebView
      source={{ uri: 'https://google.com' }}
      ref={this._refWebView}
    />
  </SafeAreaView>
  )
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug that was accidentally shipped as part of version `7.0.7` of `react-native-webview`. This fix for the bug is currently (as of the posting of this answer) in review [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/pull/886), but until it's released to avoid this bug you'll have to use a version of `react-native-webview` lower than `7.0.7`.